# List items in a directory over a certain age, then delete them

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm sure I've missed something obvious, but it's been a while since I have needed to use PowerShell (n.b. it is version 2).

I need a basic script that deletes files over a certain age (3 days). I have the following:

```cs
$logDirectory = "C:\logs\"

$days = (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)

# Delete files older than the $days
Get-ChildItem -Path $logDirectory -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $days } |
    %{Write-Host File Found: $_.fullname $_.LastWriteTime}

Get-ChildItem -Path $logDirectory -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $days } |
    Remove-Item -Force
```

This works, but If I combine the two it doesn't. And I'm sure there must be a neater way to do this where I can write out a list of files, and then delete them. Something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $logDirectory -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $days } |
    %{Write-Host File Found: $_.fullname $_.LastWriteTime} |
    Remove-Item -Force
```

But all this does is list the items, not delete them.

Comment: You need to output the object back to the pipeline, otherwise it won't reach `Remove-Item`: `... | %{ ...; $_ } | Remove-Item ...`

Comment: cheers, that has fixed it,